# Can I control storage size in Berkeley DB JE?

Tags: java, database, oracle, caching, berkeley-db-je

I want to use Berkeley DB JE like a disk cache for my application. And max size of cache should be 30 Gb. That is why I need to control it.

- Is it any ways to know the size of storage from the code (Java)?
- Can I use clearing algorithm like a LRU and Berkeley will clear the db when storage size is over 30 gb?
- Maybe some useful information about it?

And, yes, I already read oracle docs (and didn't find needed info).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Berkeley DB JE 7.5.11 or later releases, you may want to take a look at the [setMaxDisk(long totalBytes)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/je/EnvironmentMutableConfig.html#setMaxDisk-long-) API, which could be used to set the upper limit for your data storage.